# database is processing two of the same value as different?

Tags: mysql

I am recording total values in my database corresponding to the name of the person its related too with this:

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct instr from table"; //instr is the name of the person in this case
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
while($row = $q->fetch()){
    //the rest of the stuff
}
```

This has always seemed to work fine, however today i noticed it is returning two separate sets of numbers for 'caitlin' when they should be together. here is a screenshot of the query in phpma

[image: screenshot]

What could cause this?

Comment: Could be trailing space or something. Try doing a `select instr from daysheet where instr = 'caitlin'` to see what shows.

Comment: @FilipeSilva this only returns one. what would be a good way to target the one with a trailing space?

Comment: nevermind, i used `LIKE '% caitlin%' and found it. i will just throw on a trim to the query to avoid this. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would solve your problem:

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct TRIM(instr) from table";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some whitespace in there, maybe a tab character or something.

To find the errant character(s), do this:

```
select hex(instr) from daysheet
```

This will show all characters as their ascii character value in hexadecimal. Examine the output for characters outside the range 61-7A (a-z) and 41-5A (A-Z)